# Graph shifting, compression, and stretch

Tags: transformation, rational-functions

Given $f(x)$, sketch $p(x) = (1/2)f(2x-6)-3$.

I can't put the graph here. You can just tell me the order of transformation of the graph.
What i did by myself is horizontal compressing (using $2x$ in the equation) then shift the graph 6 units down (using $-6$ in the graph). Then, I did the vertical stretching (using 1/2). Finally, I move the graph down 3 units (using $-3$). Did i do it right? If not, can you give me the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right. Mostly, in this case it's important to first look at the transformation within the function argument (so in this case $2x-6$) and then at the outer modifications.

So you'd compress the graph horizontally by factor 2 (seen from the origin) and then move it 6 units to the right (**not** to the left!) and then compress it by factor 2 vertically (with respect to the x-axis) and finally move it 3 units downwards.

Comment: Is it supposed to be 1/2 vertically instead of 2?

Comment: Sorry for the bad terminology. By "compress by factor 2" I meant to "stretch by factor 0.5" (for the horizontal axis as well as for the vertical axis). So you basically squeeze the graph a lot. It's always a little confusing.